# Мне нужно вернуть с функции два значения sql, pythhon

Tags: python, sqlite3, aiogram

Этот код проверяет есть ли запись в бд
если есть выводит,нету записи на определеный день выводит True,если вовсе нету записей на мой айди, выводит False

проблема в том что self.conn.commit() остонавливает функцию после того как она выполнила свою задачу, но мне нужно ещё возвращать True or False or 1
И если я делаю так как показано ниже функция не останавливается например после того как av == bv, а делает то что там написано и проверяет дальше

вопрос в том как мне остановить функцию и возвращать True or False or 1

```
def see_schud(self, user_id_recs, day):
        user_id = user_id_recs
        av = []
        gos = BotDB.user_id_recs_checking(self, user_id_recs)
        for value in self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM recs WHERE `user_id_recs` = ?",  (user_id,)).fetchall():
            bv = [user_id_recs, day]
            av.append(value[1])
            av.append(value[2])
            print(av)
            print(bv)

            if gos == False:  #На этотайди нету записей
                return (self.conn.commit(), False)
            if av == bv: #Есть запись
                see_gop = 1
                return (self.conn.commit(), see_gop)
            if av != bv:
                g = True
                av.clear()
        if g == True: #Нету записи на определеный день
            return (self.conn.commit(), True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `conn.commit()` ничего не возвращает или если быть более точным возвращает `None`. Поэтому я не вижу смысла возвращать из функции `see_schud ()` кортеж, в котором первый элемент всегда равен `None`.

Проще и правильнее вызывать `conn.commit()` до `return`:

```
            ...
            if gos == False:  #На этотайди нету записей
                self.conn.commit()
                return False
            if av == bv: #Есть запись
                see_gop = 1
                self.conn.commit()
                return see_gop
            if av != bv:
                g = True
                av.clear()
        if g == True: #Нету записи на определеный день
            self.conn.commit()
            return True
```